# AJAX vs. Server-Side Execution with C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2008

In my previous web development experience I have used LAMP setups.  I am trying to learn the Microsoft way as I develop a project using the following tools:

- ASP.NET 3.5
- C#
- MS Visual Studio 2008

Here is my question:  How can I tell when code gets executed on the server versus code that is exectued as javascript?

I have added AJAX functionality to my aspx file using tutorials I found online.  I have something like:

ASP:

```
<asp:ScriptManager />
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input id="inputItem" type="text" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="submitButton" runat="server"
                    OnClick="submitButton_clicked"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#:

```
protected void submitButton_clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do dynamic stuff on page.
}
```

I have been able to successfully update elements on the page without requiring a refresh.  It is my understanding that the C# function submitButton_clicked() is automatically converted to javascript by Visual Studio when the web application is built (as well as any functions called by it).

I need to be able to submit the user-supplied data in this form to the server so that I can add it to a database.  What I do not understand is how to differentiate between code that is automatically converted to javascript and code that is not.  I want to be able to call functions from submitButton_clicked() which use LINQ to perform database operations, and have that code executed server-side.

I have been trying to find some online tutorials which explain this distinction cleary but have had no luck so far.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in the `submitButton_clicked` function is not converted to javascript, it executes on the server side. The use of the `UpdatePanel` allows your page to refresh the content of the `UpdatePanel` via javascript (AJAX) calls to the server, so that the user doesn't experience a full page reload. The server-side code all still runs.

You should insert some breakpoints in your code (the `Page_Load`, your `submitButton_clicked`, other places), and watch what happens when the `UpdatePanel` refreshes. The page will go through its entire life-cycle on the server-side, and the new state will be passed via AJAX to the controls in the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot more sense.  Clearly I missed that in the web tutorials I was trying to follow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from a LAMP environment you might feel more comfortable with ASP.NET MVC. It doesn't require you to understand the WebForm pattern and it may give you a feeling of comfort  being a PHP developer.

Give it a look, and see how you like it. The worst thing that can happen is that you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to understand here.

button submit behavior .
     `<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_click"  Text="btn" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>`

By default, UseSubmitBehavior is set to true.

2. `OnClick="btn1_click"` is the event which gets fired when on the server side regardless of whether UseSubmitBehavior is set to true/false
3. when submit behaviour is false, a javascript method is added for the button click, by asp.net `onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('btn1','')"`
4. if you want to add your own javascript functions on the code behind  you can  use `btn1.Attributes.Add('onclick','yourJS')` or  if in aspx/ascx side, you can use  onClientClick

`<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_click"  Text="btn"  OnClientClick="yourJS"/>`

Hope this helps